# UIActivityViewController set sourceView to UIBarButtonItem

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

For an iPhone/iPad app, i have the functionality to share when someone clicks on UIBarButtonItem.

```
UIActivityViewController * activityVC = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:shareItems applicationActivities:nil];

    [self presentViewController:activityVC animated:YES completion:nil];
```

For iPad however, this code errors because I need to set the sourceView for the activityVC.

So I need to add this code, but set it to the position of UIBarButtonItem.

```
activityVC.popoverPresentationController.sourceView = SomeUIBarButtonItem;
```

But this doesn't work since UIBarButtonItem doesn't inherit from UIView(which is really strange for me and I don't get this logic).

Is there some way to set it so that share popover appears pointing the bar button item?

Thanks,

Comment: Have you looked at the `barButtonItem` property of `UIPopoverPresentationController`?

Comment: Oh, I realized there was barButtonItem, and it works as expected! Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 59, accepted):

All you need to do is use the popover's barButtonItem property.

So a proper code to support ActivityViewController or UIAlertController on iPads:

```
popover.barButtonItem = self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem;
```

Another example for a full support for iPads, with UIAlertController (but works just the same with ActivityViewController):

```
UIPopoverPresentationController *popover = alert.popoverPresentationController;
if (popover)
{
    popover.barButtonItem = self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem;
    popover.permittedArrowDirections = UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp;
}

[self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
```

**Swift 4.2**

```
if let popover = alert.popoverPresentationController {
     popover.barButtonItem  = self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem
     popover.permittedArrowDirections = .up
}

self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: `barButtonItem` will be deprecated. Instead, use `sourceItem`: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uipopoverpresentationcontroller/3930371-sourceitem

Comment: Keep in mind: `sourceItem` needs min version iOS16 so as of now this is probably not a solution for most projects (which still support one or more versions back)